# react bind to word download instead of icon

Tags: reactjs

I simply just want to bind this path to the word Link instead of the icon...can someone please tell me what change do i make so that this would bind correctly. Thanks

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<a href="`${docLibPath}/${listItem.Title}/${listItem.Filename}.mp3}`">Link</a><br><br>

 <IconButton iconProps={checkCurrentAudioPlaying(`${docLibPath}/${listItem.Title}/${listItem.Filename}.mp3`) ? pauseIcon : playIcon} title={checkCurrentAudioPlaying(`${docLibPath}/${listItem.Title}/${listItem.Filename}.mp3`) ? "Pause" : "Play"} ariaLabel={checkCurrentAudioPlaying(`${docLibPath}/${listItem.Title}/${listItem.Filename}.mp3`) ? "Pause" : "Play"} className={classNames.salmon} onClick={() => togglePlay(`${docLibPath}/${listItem.Title}/${listItem.Filename}.mp3`)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that in anchor tag

```
<a href={`${docLibPath}/${listItem.Title}/${listItem.Filename}.mp3}`}>Link</a><br><br>
```